# Cygwin C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, mingw

When installing Cygwin, when selecting a C++ compiler I see the following options:
`mingw-gcc-g++`, `gcc4-g++` and `gcc-g++`
Can anyone tell me the difference between these? And which would I would want to use?

Also what's the point of the `gcc-mingw-g++` headers?
What's "Mingw32 support"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- MinGW vs. Cygwin: There are two layers for porting unix applications to windows:

  - Cygwin. This tries to emulate environment closely, but that makes it more difficult to integrate with native applications. Cygwin library is dual-licensed GPL or commercial, so to link commercial application against it, you need to purchase a license.
  - [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/). This is much lighter layer that only emulates some basic things and requires more porting effort to get the application working, but integrates better with native applications (paths are passed in native format and only converted inside the applications, does not use virtual mounts etc.). I believe the licensing is also more liberal.
  - In fact, Windows are POSIX compliant, so none of that should be actually needed. [Windows Services For Unix](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=274) from Microsoft should provide compatibility.

    The `mingw` compiler builds binaries using the MinGW libraries, the other variants use the `cygwin1` library.
- gcc/gcc4 is just different versions.

Comment: Windows Services For Unix is obviously for Unix platform and so off-topic here.

Comment: @ber4444: "Windows Services For Unix" is Windows utilities making Windows more compatible with Unix. The name is somewhat misleading.

Comment: in that case the Microsoft website is even more misleading which says: "Windows Services for UNIX 3.5 provides ... services for enterprise customers to use in integrating Windows into their existing UNIX-based environments."

Comment: @ber4444: In the best Microsoft tradition that sentence is correct, but totally useless. The [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) article clearly says it "provides a Unix subsystem and other parts of a full Unix environment on Windows NT and some of its immediate successor operating-systems."

Answer (score 1):

From looking at [the contents of gcc-g++ package](http://cygwin.com/packages/gcc-g++/), it appears to be gcc 3.x.  So the difference between gcc4-g++ and gcc-g++ is whether you want gcc 3.x or 4.x.

Mingw is "is a minimalist development environment for native Microsoft Windows applications".  See: http://www.mingw.org/.  Presumably the mingw-gcc-g++ package will allow you to target (i.e., build binaries that use) mingw.